# Create Edges in Boost Graph using Multi Threading

Tags: boost, boost-graph

I am trying to create a boost graph with more than 50K nodes (It will map the configuration space of a robot) and I want to create edges between the node using multi threading as it has become a bottleneck for my program.
I store all the vertices' index in a hash map so that they are easy for lookup while adding edges. For each vertex I find 5 nearest neighbors that are to be connected.

Also I have disabled parallel edges in the graph and the graph definition is

```
 using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;
```

For finding the nearest neighbours, I use Local Senstivity Hashing ([github_repo](https://github.com/PetropoulakisPanagiotis/nearest-neighbor-search)).

```
model* myModel;
myModel = new lshEuclidean();

myModel->fit(datapoints, status);  /// training on all leaf nodes that are not in collision
```

Also before connecting the edges, I insert all the vertices in the graph and also make a hash map so that it is easy to recover the vertex index for adding an edge. (For quick testing, I convert the vector to a string to store in the hashmap, I know this is inefficient and need to make my own hash function)

```
BoostGraph::VertexProperties vp1;

BoostGraph graph(5);

std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map;
    
    for(int center = 0; center < finalLeafNodes.size(); center++){

    Vec origin = finalLeafNodes[center]->getOrigin();
        std::vector<double> joint_angle = {origin.at(0)*toRadians, origin.at(1)*toRadians, origin.at(2)*toRadians,
                                            origin.at(3)*toRadians, origin.at(4)*toRadians};

        Eigen::VectorXd joint_angle_center;
        joint_angle_center.resize(5);
        joint_angle_center << joint_angle[0], joint_angle[1], joint_angle[2], joint_angle[3], joint_angle[4];

        vp1.joint_angles = joint_angle;
        BoostGraph::Vertex v_center = graph.AddVertex(vp1);
        int vertex_index_center = graph.getVertexIndex(v_center);

        Vec joint_angle_in_vector_degrees = origin;
        
        std::stringstream output;
        std::copy(joint_angle_in_vector_degrees.begin(), joint_angle_in_vector_degrees.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(output, " "));

        map[output.str()] = vertex_index_center;

    }
```

Then for each vertex node, I find neighbours in a given radius, sort them to nearest neighbour and take top 3/5 and add an edge by finding those neighbours vertex index through the hashmap mentioned above. I also have a local planner that checks if the path between two points will also be collision free or not. If its collision free, edge is added.

```
neighbors.sort([&query](Item &a, Item &b) -> bool {compare(a, b, query);});
```

```
 auto edge = graph.AddEdge(center_iterator->second, neighbour_iterator->second, BoostGraph::EdgeProperties{(double)recursion_index + 1.});
```

Also I am now trying on a five degree of freedom robot, so the dimension has also increased.

I have tried multi threading with mutex_lock() but its not giving much of a speedup.

Is there a way to create a shared memory object where I can store the all the edges in multi threading and just loop over it to add the edges in the graph so that I don't have parallel edges.

Comment: Do you have a self contained example that demonstrates the issue? It is unclear wherre the actual bottle neck is at the moment, as we don't know how you e.g. _find 5 nearest neighbors_. It may not be relevant - in that case the self-contained reproducer will show this.

Comment: I added some more information to the question about how neighbours and vertex index are found.

Comment: "I know this is inefficient and need to make my own hash function" - yup. Outrageously so. Compare: `-DSLOW_HASH` has 4x slower perf, even doing only lookups of the nodes already queried spatially: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd543b2fd0c8ddd2

Comment: At this point I'm not inclined to try to piece together how the rest of the code is done, I'm pretty sure that you can find the right pointers in my answer. They definitely apply without much change even if you choose a different library to help with spatial query. Of course, if you have the full code I can be (even) more concretely helpful

Comment: (lol - better comparison of the hash functions http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4774fc7e9e9ba361 by themselves: 347.248μs
 vs. 105722μs - a 300x slow-down); Also lots less room for the optimizer, e.g. when you forget to use the values (commented just `return` from `main`): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62a0ae370c81d1a9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create edges between the node using multi threading as it has become a bottleneck for my program

Frequently the solution will be to change the choice of datastructure or algorithm. And it is quite likely that the time is actually spent doing other things than actually inserting edges.

In some cases you will even want to have a graph model that is just an edge list.

Here's a implementation of your description (using parts of the code from previous questions). In some sense it is straight-forward. In some sense it might show you some advanced algorithm/datastructure ideas. I think it doesn't have the performance bottleneck you are talking about?

### Generating Input Data

Let's read vertices from CSV data. Generating 50k input lines:

**[Live On Coliru: `gen.cpp`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f5bba89e050ebaf)**

```
./a.out > input.txt; wc -l input.txt;  tail input.txt
50000 input.txt
-0.54953,0.309816,1.49314
-1.38758,1.10754,1.12841
0.468204,-1.38628,1.29798
1.44672,-0.600287,-1.1688
1.28432,-1.40215,0.701882
1.4669,-0.215648,-0.404705
-0.701017,-0.130071,-0.62072
1.3742,-0.639261,1.44033
-1.17127,-1.48499,-1.03837
-1.16458,-1.19539,-0.946286
```

### Parsing Vertices From Input Data

Note I included the optimization I suggested in an earlier question:

```
using JointAngles = std::array<double, 3>;
```

This also makes it easier later on to use geometry algorithms.

The parsing is not really related to the question, so posted as-is:

```
template <typename F> size_t read_vertices(std::string_view input, F callback) {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    using boost::fusion::at_c;

    Vertex n      = 0;
    auto   action = [&](auto& ctx) {
        auto& vv = _attr(ctx);
        callback(JointAngles{at_c<0>(vv), at_c<1>(vv), at_c<2>(vv)});
        n += 1;
    };
    static auto const line = (double_ >> ',' >> double_ >> ',' >> double_)[action];

    parse(begin(input), end(input), skip(blank)[line % (eol | eoi) > (*eol >> eoi)]);
    return n;
}
```

Note how it is a whitespace tolerant where possible and supports ±inf/nan.

### A Spatial Index

Instead of brute-forcing our way, let's use a [Spatial Index](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes.html) from Boost Geometry. What this will allow us to do is find the nearest-k points much cheaper than bruteforce.

Firstly, include the relevant headers:

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/std_array.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/adaptors/query.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
```

Now, let's tell Boost Geometry about our point type, and define a `Tree` type:

```
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_STD_ARRAY_CS(bg::cs::cartesian)

namespace bg  = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = bg::index;
using Tree = bgi::rtree<std::pair<JointAngles, Vertex>, bgi::rstar<16>>;
```

We choose `R*` packing algorithm, which should usually give us [best `nearest()` performance at the cost of higher insertion](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/introduction.html) cost:

[image]

### Actually Read The Graph

Using the parsing function above, let's build the graph *and* the spatial index tree at once:

```
int main() {
    // read and index vertices
    Tree  tree;
    Graph graph;

    std::ifstream ifs("input.txt", std::ios::binary);
    std::string const input(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});

    graph.m_vertices.reserve(50'000);
    auto const n = read_vertices(input, [&](JointAngles ja) {
        tree.insert({ja, add_vertex(VertexProperties{ja}, graph)});
    });
    std::cout << "Parsed " << n << " vertices, indexed: " << tree.size()
              << " graph: " << num_vertices(graph) << "\n";
```

That's all. Note how each inserted point in the tree carries the vertex descriptor as meta data, so we can correlate vertices with tree nodes.

This code will print, as expected, for our generated `input.txt`:

```
Parsed 50000 vertices, indexed: 50000 graph: 50000
```

### Adding 5-nearest edges

Using a bgi query this is pretty simple. Likely this can be optimized, but let's do the naive thing first, just to see whether the performance is reasonable:

```
// connect 5-degree nearest vertices
size_t added = 0, dups =0;
for (auto& [vja, v] : tree) {
    for (auto& [uja, u] : tree | queried(bgi::nearest(vja, 6))) {
        if (v == u)
            continue;
        auto w       = bg::distance(vja, uja);
        auto [e, ok] = add_edge(v, u, EdgeProperties{w}, graph);
        //std::cout << (ok ? "Added " : "Duplicate ") << e << " weight " << w << "\n";
        (ok? added:dups)++;
    }
}
std::cout << "Total edges added:" << added << " dups:" << dups << "\n";
```

Note that we omit self-edges, and rely on `setS` and `undirectedS` to detect duplicates - which are obviously expected. This prints, for our test data:

```
Total edges added:150778 dups:99222
```

### BONUS: A* search

Like in your previous question, let's perform an A* search between arbitrary vertices:

```
// do A* search
std::vector<Vertex> predecessors(n);
std::vector<double> distances(n);

auto vidx      = get(boost::vertex_index, graph); // redundant with vecS
auto pmap      = make_iterator_property_map(predecessors.data(), vidx);
auto dmap      = make_iterator_property_map(distances.data(), vidx);
auto weightmap = get(&EdgeProperties::weight, graph);

std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());
Vertex       start = random_vertex(graph, gen);
Vertex       goal  = random_vertex(graph, gen);

try {
    // call astar named parameter interface
    auto heuristic = [&, gja = graph[goal].joint_angles](Vertex u) {
        return bg::distance(graph[u].joint_angles, gja);
    };
    astar_search( //
        graph, start, heuristic,
        boost::predecessor_map(pmap) //
            .distance_map(dmap)
            .weight_map(weightmap)
            .visitor(goal_visitor{goal}));

    fmt::print("{} -> {}: No path\n", start, goal);
} catch (goal_visitor::found) {
    std::list<Vertex> path;
    for (auto cursor = goal;;) {
        path.push_front(cursor);
        auto previous = std::exchange(cursor, predecessors.at(cursor));
        if (cursor == previous)
            break;
    }

    fmt::print("{} -> {}: {}\n", start, goal, path);
}
```

As you can see everything is basically unchanged, except the `distance_heuristic` class has been replaced by the much simpler lambda:

```
    auto heuristic = [&, gja = graph[goal].joint_angles](Vertex u) {
        return bg::distance(graph[u].joint_angles, gja);
    };
```

This effectively does the same as your manual heuristic, except potentially smarter - who knows :).

Possible outputs. Doing 1000 random searches took ~1.8s:

```
Parsed 50000 vertices, indexed: 50000 graph: 50000 0.161082s
Total edges added:150778 dups:99222 0.190395s
7489 -> 8408: [7489, 23635, 34645, 41337, 1725, 46184, 25161, 33297, 30471, 37500, 4073, 30763, 4488, 30949, 9505, 48543, 33639, 35640, 19525, 34765, 18439, 21830, 4170, 27552, 22621, 6327, 8277, 8082, 15932, 23390, 8408]
6968 -> 49906: [6968, 43210, 9331, 36641, 15088, 45635, 47530, 9136, 18177, 30781, 46243, 21125, 12868, 42416, 46187, 24824, 39841, 39095, 13494, 27104, 34973, 49906]
39242 -> 46236: [39242, 34365, 14041, 30310, 8757, 35459, 41035, 32883, 1552, 24120, 43646, 38812, 17835, 14082, 46568, 37492, 17564, 4934, 28288, 20393, 924, 14615, 15993, 39413, 10407, 46236]
--
31949 -> 38708: [31949, 16473, 18328, 20099, 22828, 42868, 46176, 22766, 49370, 17479, 636, 6173, 36367, 32040, 16961, 48438, 18883, 44611, 19468, 4095, 18156, 33083, 12925, 41017, 17514, 17765, 19710, 25790, 46668, 28202, 12010, 39520, 17796, 45443, 9474, 17370, 5071, 27279, 17083, 3503, 11401, 11209, 32403, 23265, 38708]
9895 -> 41286: [9895, 7793, 34802, 28190, 24889, 578, 49750, 20217, 41057, 2637, 24109, 4262, 38363, 11680, 7513, 39893, 21158, 15747, 33531, 11051, 7893, 31583, 45825, 18988, 38405, 13631, 31016, 45820, 9078, 37368, 28401, 14573, 9294, 6214, 28330, 22949, 10575, 41286]
42176 -> 37875: [42176, 12091, 19799, 41080, 47399, 30041, 41714, 10766, 8904, 41305, 4973, 21270, 18139, 29246, 34739, 35599, 11807, 36557, 48764, 9641, 3619, 11747, 34201, 33629, 20414, 24646, 43402, 36831, 7384, 29363, 24768, 33415, 41325, 17709, 32108, 42284, 28683, 5310, 1506, 14339, 27331, 14861, 7152, 37211, 22754, 7602, 48398, 27378, 39577, 37875]
Total search time: 1.79371s

real    0m2,209s
user    0m2,160s
sys     0m0,044s
```

### Complete Benchmark

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46c05785edb1f59e)**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_array.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/astar_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <random>
static auto now = &std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

using JointAngles = std::array<double, 3>;

struct VertexProperties {
    JointAngles joint_angles{0, 0, 0};
};

struct EdgeProperties {
    double weight = 0;
};

using Graph  = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
                                    VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

template <typename F> size_t read_vertices(std::string_view input, F callback) {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    using boost::fusion::at_c;

    Vertex n      = 0;
    auto   action = [&](auto& ctx) {
        auto& vv = _attr(ctx);
        callback(JointAngles{at_c<0>(vv), at_c<1>(vv), at_c<2>(vv)});
        n += 1;
    };
    static auto const line = (double_ >> ',' >> double_ >> ',' >> double_)[action];

    parse(begin(input), end(input), skip(blank)[line % (eol | eoi) > (*eol >> eoi)]);
    return n;
}

// visitor that terminates when we find the goal
struct goal_visitor : boost::default_astar_visitor {
    struct found {}; // exception for termination
    Vertex m_goal;

    goal_visitor(Vertex g) : m_goal(g) {}

    template <class Graph> void examine_vertex(Vertex u, Graph&) {
        if (u == m_goal)
            throw found{};
    }
};

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/std_array.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/adaptors/query.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
namespace bg  = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = bg::index;
using bgi::adaptors::queried;
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_STD_ARRAY_CS(bg::cs::cartesian)
using Tree = bgi::rtree<std::pair<JointAngles, Vertex>, bgi::rstar<16>>;

int main() {
    auto elapsed = [start = now()]() mutable {
        auto n = now();
        return (n - std::exchange(start, n)) / 1.0s;
    };
    // read and index vertices
    Tree  tree;
    Graph graph;

    std::ifstream ifs("input.txt", std::ios::binary);
    std::string const input(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});

    graph.m_vertices.reserve(50'000);
    auto const n = read_vertices(input, [&](JointAngles ja) {
        tree.insert({ja, add_vertex(VertexProperties{ja}, graph)});
    });
    std::cout << "Parsed " << n << " vertices, indexed: " << tree.size()
              << " graph: " << num_vertices(graph) << " " << elapsed() << "s\n";

    assert(n == tree.size());
    assert(n == num_vertices(graph));

    // connect 5-degree nearest vertices
    size_t added = 0, dups =0;
    for (auto& [vja, v] : tree) {
        for (auto& [uja, u] : tree | queried(bgi::nearest(vja, 6))) {
            if (v == u)
                continue;
            auto w       = bg::distance(vja, uja);
            auto [e, ok] = add_edge(v, u, EdgeProperties{w}, graph);
            //std::cout << (ok ? "Added " : "Duplicate ") << e << " weight " << w << "\n";
            (ok? added:dups)++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Total edges added:" << added << " dups:" << dups << " " << elapsed() << "s\n";

    // do A* search
    std::vector<Vertex> predecessors(n);
    std::vector<double> distances(n);

    for (auto i = 0; i < 1'000; ++i) {
        auto vidx      = get(boost::vertex_index, graph); // redundant with vecS
        auto pmap      = make_iterator_property_map(predecessors.data(), vidx);
        auto dmap      = make_iterator_property_map(distances.data(), vidx);
        auto weightmap = get(&EdgeProperties::weight, graph);

        std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());
        Vertex       start = random_vertex(graph, gen);
        Vertex       goal  = random_vertex(graph, gen);

        try {
            // call astar named parameter interface
            auto heuristic = [&, gja = graph[goal].joint_angles](Vertex u) {
                return bg::distance(graph[u].joint_angles, gja);
            };
            astar_search( //
                    graph, start, heuristic,
                    boost::predecessor_map(pmap) //
                    .distance_map(dmap)
                    .weight_map(weightmap)
                    .visitor(goal_visitor{goal}));

            fmt::print("{} -> {}: No path\n", start, goal);
        } catch (goal_visitor::found) {
            std::list<Vertex> path;
            for (auto cursor = goal;;) {
                path.push_front(cursor);
                auto previous = std::exchange(cursor, predecessors.at(cursor));
                if (cursor == previous)
                    break;
            }

            fmt::print("{} -> {}: {}\n", start, goal, path);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Total search time: " << elapsed() << "s\n";
}
```

On Coliru, takes a little longer:

```
Parsed 50000 vertices, indexed: 50000 graph: 50000 0.252916s
Total edges added:150778 dups:99222 0.38979s
43176 -> 2998: [43176, 8919, 27234, 38221, 8714, 2907, 45819, 32924, 33376, 14539, 9174, 19001, 30909, 3923, 36332, 4521, 43005, 31867, 7326, 46231, 20699, 24026, 44641, 21918, 43012, 37366, 2800, 14239, 21197, 26989, 38269, 16522, 25964, 18224, 47148, 21553, 19350, 37546, 41390, 1247, 2998]
19955 -> 30654: [19955, 18833, 24521, 9310, 29015, 5746, 46264, 7706, 4929, 11078, 41910, 30676, 26759, 16638, 3075, 23001, 9322, 38446, 20634, 1120, 30761, 47535, 15750, 10039, 34123, 42874, 22325, 24136, 30285, 34230, 23926, 9978, 4427, 23805, 10436, 41678, 46936, 37189, 30654]
45710 -> 21757: [45710, 45416, 1375, 16480, 21730, 22843, 15897, 33652, 12561, 46834, 23178, 44302, 21027, 15457, 38383, 14716, 26787, 20697, 41752, 42153, 44194, 21757]
--
16543 -> 43355: [16543, 44982, 27516, 6578, 27706, 39013, 35842, 33455, 30460, 22955, 579, 46537, 43224, 6811, 1651, 41054, 21637, 9496, 36577, 21896, 49329, 43355]
2856 -> 24431: [2856, 21766, 1449, 2525, 15156, 6325, 23773, 25733, 48449, 24269, 49865, 34213, 47119, 48167, 12609, 46284, 33395, 10107, 26726, 14078, 28431, 33884, 468, 39873, 42529, 32395, 49457, 44554, 2207, 47678, 4783, 14247, 39638, 8510, 9439, 20570, 18018, 34614, 37184, 17579, 49921, 8755, 44316, 24431]
17195 -> 21888: [17195, 38851, 28287, 18829, 14051, 28305, 32206, 11044, 6989, 30201, 49002, 19410, 6456, 47912, 35145, 9286, 17782, 10294, 14344, 49966, 49634, 5262, 12496, 45270, 20093, 11298, 7202, 15409, 41313, 35934, 14510, 17221, 23121, 49522, 38138, 45948, 43564, 7840, 4456, 32016, 16660, 5832, 7578, 380, 9925, 18908, 38131, 36929, 28073, 21888]
Total search time: 3.41871s
```

Comment: And this is just scratching the surface. Adding some flags and using [`comparable_distance`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/distance/comparable_distance_2.html) for the heuristic [shaved off >50%](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a29127ed2620cbeb) of the search time.

Comment: Locally winning about 15% using custom edge (`smallSetS`): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/577417cc0af12525 (net 35% of original coliru run - using a different seed for `gen` though, and also took `mt19937` construction outside the loop)

Comment: Hi, I am not able to compile the above code on my machine. The gcc/g++ version is 11.1 and Boost version is 1.80.0. The log is here https://pastebin.com/G22jXLJn. Is there some additional dependencies I need to add?

Comment: @SamarthJain which exact version are you trying to compile, so I can relate source lines to the message?

Comment: This one. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/577417cc0af12525

Comment: Good thing I asked! Anyways, I can build it with [gcc 11.3/boost 1.80](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/oEds8ed1f). [gcc 11.1](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/sP1qY3Gf3) as well. It looks like your version of the standard library (libstdc++) doesn't match? Because [member `rebind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator#:~:text=rebind) was deprecated/removed in c++17/c++20

Comment: Honestly it looks like you're not using Boost 1.80. The use of `.template rebind` has been dropped from Boost Geometry in [8e5fb4f28](https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/commit/8e5fb4f28362481d424d6bbfb2bf3321e00320f8) and [cedbf5e070](https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/commit/cedbf5e0700d6fa4e20f662d82f6d253e2377292) which matches boost 1.67 (the [issue](https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/pull/445)).

Comment: Here's a version that works with boost 1.66 and c++14: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/WE6TKha3E, and the same but also without libfmt: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/6fqvnE5ha.

Comment: I am trying the new https://compiler-explorer.com/z/WE6TKha3E and the output is https://pastebin.com/BjK29rbk. I also included the cmake output, its finds boost 1.80. The template issue in /boost/math/special_functions/math_fwd.hpp:157:35 is coming up. I have both boost 1.65 and 1.80 as there are some dependencies I cannot remove.

Comment: Note how the include paths are completely different now! Earlier your pastebin had [/usr/include/boost/ includes](https://pastebin.com/G22jXLJn#:~:text=/usr/include/boost/geometry/index/detail/rtree/node/variant_static.hpp) instead of the /home/jainsamarth/local/include/boost. So, at the very least you're not being consistent with your build config. I **can** look at the new errors, but it's a bit... hard to follow a moving target. I was working on this in the meantime: More simplified and even c++11-only: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/ePqMdGhjW

Comment: The math error is a known issue fixed in develop (also in 1.81.0-beta1)

Comment: Hi, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/577417cc0af12525 works. I had wrong CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS flags in the CMakeList, I commented those out and it worked. Can the flags cause linking error?

Comment: Everything that manipulates your preprocessor (defines and includes) can cause linker errors. CXX_FLAGS is so general, it can contain any compiler flag so you can break everything there, in principle :)